# Size of maximum clique given a fixed amount of edges?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given an undirected graph $G = (V,E)$, what is the clique number $\omega(G)$ given $|E|$, *i.e.*, the size of the largest clique in a graph with $|E|$ edges.

I think this is doable after realizing that the number of edges in a clique is equal to the *[triangular number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number)*:
$$|E(K_k)| = \frac{1}{2}k(k-1).$$

I am looking for a closed formula.

Comment: Do you mean the maximal possible clique? Or finding the maximal clique size in a specific graph?
The maximal possible size will clearly be $\min\{|V|,t\}$, where ${t\choose 2}=k$. Finding the maximal clique is NP-complete.

Comment: I'm looking for the maximal possible Clique. What does t refer to in this case?

Comment: $t$ is the solution to the equation $t(t-1)/2=k$. Intuitively - $t$ is the number of vertices you need for a clique with $k$ edges.

Answer (score 3):

The graph can have clique number 1 (if we allow the graph to be disconnected), or 2 (consider a long path).  The graph can have a clique of size at most
$$\frac{1}{2} (\sqrt{8m + 1} + 1),$$
where $m = |E|$, provided of course that $|V|$ is large enough.